# How to specify the position of the table in a pdf file using iTextsharp in c#

Tags: c#, itext

I have created a pdf file that has graphics on it, now am trying to add a table under those graphics. My problem is the table is over the graphics, how do i specify the location/position where i want my table to be placed on the pdf document??

This is my code

```
        docl.Open();
        docl.Add(new Paragraph("My first PDF file"));

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        //employee
        //                position y,position x,length,height,  unknown
        cb.RoundRectangle(   20f,      745f,     200f,   35f,      10f);
        //title
        cb.RoundRectangle(235f, 745f, 35f, 35f, 10f);
        //identity number
        cb.RoundRectangle(280f, 745f, 105f, 35f, 10f);
        //date of birth
        cb.RoundRectangle(390f, 745f, 105f, 35f, 10f);
        //employee number
        cb.RoundRectangle(500f, 745f, 105f, 35f, 10f);
        //address
        cb.RoundRectangle(20f, 660f, 200f, 80f, 10f);
        //pay method
        cb.RoundRectangle(235f, 700f, 35f, 35f, 10f);
        //brantch code
        cb.RoundRectangle(235f, 660f, 35f, 35f, 10f);
        //bank
        cb.RoundRectangle(280f, 700f, 215f, 35f, 10f);
        //account type
        cb.RoundRectangle(500f, 700f, 105f, 35f, 10f);
        //account number
        cb.RoundRectangle(280f, 660f, 160f, 35f, 10f);
        //pay point
        cb.RoundRectangle(445f, 660f, 35f, 35f, 10f);
        //date of payment
        cb.RoundRectangle(506f, 660f, 90f, 35f, 10f);
        //marital status
        cb.RoundRectangle(20f, 600f, 35f, 35f, 10f);
        //gender
        cb.RoundRectangle(60f, 600f, 35f, 35f, 10f);
        //date of appointment
        cb.RoundRectangle(100f, 600f, 70f, 35f, 10f);
        //Tax number
        cb.RoundRectangle(175f, 600f, 70f, 35f, 10f);
        cb.Stroke();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        table.SetTotalWidth(new float[] { 800, 200 }); 
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("EARNINGS"));
        cell.Colspan = 2;
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
        table.AddCell(cell);
        table.AddCell("Description");
        table.AddCell("Amount");
```

I used this line to specify the position of the graphics on the document: 
//                position y, position x,length,height,  unknown
cb.RoundRectangle(   20f,      745f,     200f,   35f,      10f);

[image: This how my document looks:]

I want to place the table below the graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the low-level approach (adding content at absolute positions) with the high-level approach (using `document.add()`) for page content.

Either you stick to the high-level approach, by using a table to create the round rectangles. You can create tables with borders that have rounded corners using cell and table events. When you use `document.add()`, iText will take care of positioning everything (including splitting the table if it doesn't fit the page).

Or you stick to the low-level approach, by adding the table at an absolute position, but be aware that itext won't split the table if it doesn't fit the page.

Take a look at this example: [Java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=96) | [C#](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter05/PdfCalendar.cs) | [PDF](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter05/calendar.pdf)

It shows how to create rounded borders for tables by using cell events and/or table events. See the other examples of [chapter 5](http://tinyurl.com/iiacsCH05) for less complex sample code.

As you can see in the calendar example, the table is added at an absolute position using the method `table.WriteSelectedRows(...)`. As you know the coordinates of the rounded rectangles, you can use this method to add your table at an absolute position.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void DemoTableSpacing() { 
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("SpacingTest.pdf", FileMode.Create)) { 

        Document doc = new Document(); 
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs); 
        doc.Open(); 

        Paragraph paragraphTable1 = new Paragraph(); 
        paragraphTable1.SpacingAfter = 15f; 

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3); 
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("This is table 1")); 
        cell.Colspan = 3; 
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; 
        table.AddCell(cell); 
        table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 1"); 
        table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 1"); 
        table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 1"); 
        //table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 2"); 
        //table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 2"); 
        //table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 2"); 
        paragraphTable1.Add(table); 
        doc.Add(paragraphTable1); 

        Paragraph paragraphTable2 = new Paragraph(); 
        paragraphTable2.SpacingAfter = 10f; 

        table = new PdfPTable(3); 
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("This is table 2")); 
        cell.Colspan = 3; 
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; 
        table.AddCell(cell); 
        table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 1"); 
        table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 1"); 
        table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 1"); 
        table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 2"); 
        table.AddCell("Col 2 Row 2"); 
        table.AddCell("Col 3 Row 2"); 
        paragraphTable2.Add(table); 
        doc.Add(paragraphTable2); 
        doc.Close(); 
    } 
}
```

I HAVE USE THIS ONE FOR MY TABLE POSITION IN iTEXTSHARP LINK: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/351802/Its-possible-put-a-table-in-absolute-position-with

Comment: You might want to stress that the focal idea of that codeproject answer and your code is to add an empty paragraph with a `SpacingAfter` value matching the height to skip before adding the table.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Actually i am the beginner to iTextSharp and all about asp.net. I have tried by this and also i have done first table with no border and empty header. In this way I got the my requirement in my project. Thank you once gain for comment I will improve my answering in next time.